# How to manipulate a sibling element in Selenium (python)?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create a list of elements to iterate through and manipulate their sibling element, if certain conditions are met. Here's some code to explain:

```
items = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('className')
for x in items:
  if 'className2' in x.get_attribute('class'):
    try:
      'className3' in SIBLING_ELEMENT_OF_X.get_attribute('class')
      print('Success!')
    except NoSuchElementException:
      pass
```

So line 1 creates a list of all elements containing the class 'className'. I then iterate through all of the elements to see if they ALSO have a second class called 'className2'. If they do, I want it to check if the relative next sibling element has a class called 'className3'. This is where I'm stuck. I can't figure out how to reference this sibling element relative to the iterated item. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i often combine `BeautifulSoap` with selenium when going for sibling. For help check [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#going-sideways)

Comment: relative sibling means the next immediate sibling only , or you want to check for all children inside alspo

Comment: PDHide, I am trying to look at the very next sibling.

Comment: Anyone have an idea? I tried x.find_element_by_xpath('//following-sibling::div') but that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

for those interested, the solution was:

x.find_element_by_xpath('./following-sibling::div')